# javascript array objects

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/gfuKS/5/

```
var transitionInitial = {property: "none"};
var rules = ["color", "background-color"];
var transitions = [];
for ( var k = 0; k < rules.length; k++)
{
    transitions[k] = transitionInitial;
    transitions[k].property = rules[k];
    alert(transitions[0].property);
}​
```

Why at the second iteration transitions[0].property equals "background-color"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you are storing a reference to `transitionInitial`, not a copy of it. `transitionInitial` points to an object in memory, and you are storing a reference to this object in `transitions[k]`. Regardless of the iteration you are at, you are always changing the same object.

Answer (score 3):

It's because both values in your `transitions` array are pointing at the same object.  During the execution of your code you produce one object that has three different references (`transitionInitial`, `transistions[0]`, & `transistions[1]`).

During the first iteration of the loop, `transistions[0]` is set to reference the `transitionInitial` object.  Then the `property` property of that object is set to the value `"color"`.  During the second iteration `transitions[1]` is set to reference the same object as `transitionInitial` and `transitions[0]`.  You then reset the `property`'s value to `"background-color"`.

To solve this create different objects for each of your array indexes:

```
// Not needed anymore:
// var transitionInitial = {property: "none"};
var rules = ["color", "background-color"];
var transitions = [];
for ( var k = 0; k < rules.length; k++) {
  transitions[k] = {};
  transitions[k].property = rules[k];
  alert(transitions[0].property);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have anything with this to do maybe? `for ( var k = 0; k < rules.length; k++)`
Try changing the timer.